# javascript form:- how do i give variables different values on the total

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

hey guys so basically this form is meant to have each chapter of the book at £2 which i have and then the entire book-PDF will be £8 and the entire book printed will be £15 plus postage and packaging...
i currently can not seem to get the last two prices and postage to differ from the chapters would appreciate any help thanks

```
  <!--below is the text boxes which the user will use to define the amount of copies that they need -->

 Chapter 1 - Please enter how many copies you would like <br>

 <input class="textbox"type="Number" maxlength="24"  id="ch1" placeholder="0"><br><br>

 Chapter 2 - Please enter how many copies you would like <br>

 <input class="textbox"type="text" maxlength="24" id="ch2" placeholder="0"><br><br>

 Chapter 3 - Please enter how many copies you would like <br>

 <input class="textbox"type="text" maxlength="24" id="ch3" placeholder="0"><br><br>

 Chapter 4 - Please enter how many copies you would like <br>

 <input class="textbox"type="text" maxlength="24" id="ch4" placeholder="0"><br><br>

 Chapter 5 - Please enter how many copies you would like <br>

 <input class="textbox"type="text" maxlength="24" id="ch5" placeholder="0"><br><br>

Entire Book - PDF <br>

 <input class="textbox"type="text" maxlength="24" id="ebk" placeholder="0"><br><br>

Entire Book - Printed <br>

 <input class="textbox"type="text" maxlength="24" id="prnt" placeholder="0"><br><br>

  <b> Total :  <output id = "total"> 0 </output></b><br>

  <b> Postage :  <output id = "postage"> 0 </output></b><br>

  <b> Grand Total :  <output id = "grandtotal"> 0 </output></b><br>

  <!-- below is a button which calls the javascript file -->

    <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calcu" onclick="calc()">

    <br><br>
```

```
<button type="submit">Payment</button>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

function calc(){

 var ch1 = document.getElementById("ch1").value;

 var ch2 = document.getElementById("ch2").value;

 var ch3 = document.getElementById("ch3").value;

 var ch4 = document.getElementById("ch4").value;

 var ch5 = document.getElementById("ch5").value;

 var tot = document.getElementById("total");

 var post = document.getElementById("postage");

 var ebk = document.getElementById("bk1").value;

 var prnt = document.getElementById("prnt").value;

 tot = (Number(ch1) + Number(ch2) + Number(ch3) + Number(ch4) + Number(ch5))         * 2;

  if (prnt.value > = 0) {
   tot = Number(ebk) * 8;
   }


  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = tot;

}

</script>
```

Comment: In Javascript you are using ID `bk1` but in HTML you are using `ebk`. And you should use `.value` for `total` and `postage` elements as well. Also you are misusing `output` tag, please refer to this page for more information: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_output.asp

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var x = 10;
x += 5;
```

This will result as 15.